# vizualize distance matrix as network in R

Tags: r, networking, visualization, distance-matrix

I'm trying to find a way to visualize distance matrices as a network. I came across this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832966/8767973

While very helpful, I don't have enough familiarity with R to know what the differences are between using qgraph, igraph, or ggnet.

I have 9 samples, each can be represented by a vector. I've calculated two distance matrices using either Euclidean or Mahalanobis and I would like to be able to visualize both as separate networks. I think I need to use some implementation of a force-directed graph drawing algorithm.

Thank you

Comment: I would like to visualize the distance matrix in a coordinate space where the length of line connecting two points is representative of the magnitude of calculated distance metric - almost like a PCA plot, but without reducing dimensions and where the distance between points is based on a distance matrix rather than variance.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you want to plot: the Mahalanobis Distance for a 5x5 matrix is a 5-element vector. Is that what you are trying to visualize, and would you mind posting example code to produce something that looks like your data?